# Rdkit Argument Error while calculating descriptors

Tags: python, descriptor, rdkit

I am working with RDkit and want to calculate descriptors. But I am stuck at at an ArgumentError and not able to resolve it. Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit import DataStructs
from rdkit.Chem import Descriptors
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
from utility import FeatureGenerator
data = pd.read_csv('E:/RDkit/Nitro aromatic.csv')
PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(data,'SMILES','mol',includeFingerprints=True)
data.head()
data['mol'] = data.SMILES.apply(Chem.MolFromSmiles)
data.head()
data.loc[:,'MolLogP'] = data['mol'].apply(Descriptors.MolLogP)
```

This is the error:

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in rdkit.Chem.rdMolDescriptors.CalcCrippenDescriptors(NoneType)
    did not match C++ signature:
        CalcCrippenDescriptors(class RDKit::ROMol mol, bool includeHs=True, bool force=False)
```

Comment: It seems you have corrupt SMILES. With correct SMILES your code works for me.

Comment: What should I do now, SMILES was download from CSD and has been already read.

Comment: When the SMILES is corrupt then in the `mol` column you will found a `NONE` instead a mol object.

Comment: now the situation is ,the mol colunmn has been read from SMLES. For example, the SMILES "Cc1ccccc1NN=C(C)c1cccc(c1)N(=O)=O",mol column show"<img data-content="rdkit/molecule" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAIAAAAiOjnJAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAYKUlEQVR4nO3deVhTx/oH8DfsChRRWwUkKFAX5HJFKy5YqUvdcX2w17WuYF2x1uX+rJW21gd3WqsXaatFbbXaUuVet....",this means SMILES  has corrupt?

Comment: `print(data[['SMILES','mol']])` When in the mol column you find a `None` - the SMILES is corrupt

Comment: OK，Tks,I will try

Comment: Hi,Bro. I print(data[['SMILES','mol']]), but the columa do not have None, show '<img data-content="rdkit/molecule" src="data:i...',  that means SMILES has not corrupt?

Comment: It seems that the SMILES are good - I have no clue what the problem could be.

Comment: The input to `Descriptors.MolLogP` should be a RdKit object. In your case, it seems like the `mol` column has image objects instead. Avoid using the`.apply()` function and try doing it in a simple python `for` loop. Or don't create a `mol` column at all but rather store all the mols in a python list and then see if it helps

Comment: @betelgeuse If you `print` a dataframe from PandasTools, it will turn the mols into images. In the dataframe itself they are still mol objects. I tested the above code with correct SMILES and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Testing your code on one of the SMILES that you mentioned in the comments works for me.

I am running the code on Colab.

rdkit version `2022.9.4`

I installed rdkit with:

```
!pip install rdkit
```

Here is a screenshot of the code and output:

[image]